# Bamboo sharing large artifacts between jobs

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-artifacts

I'm having issues with builds taking longer because the artifacts creation at the end of a jobs is increasing build time. Additionally, jobs that require the artifact add additional build time when retrieving the artifacts.

A solution to this issue I thought would be to have a jobs perform work on the same  work space.

What are the typically conventions/solutions for passing large artifacts between jobs or in other continuous integration tools?

Answer (score 0):

There're few options:

- pack your artifacts into one file to improve transfer performance between agent and server
- use network drive shared between different agents to share artifacts without sending them to server.
- use dedicated artifact storage server like Nexus or Artifactory
- use same agent to build are jobs which require same artifact (not scalable)